# How can I start the latexpdf number at 150 using sphinx

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

I have a sphinx documentation https://data-storage-tag-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

which I want to integrate into a PDF as an appendix, for this I want the generated PDF to
start with a different page number (150). How can I achieve this using the .conf file?

I have tried this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341897/include-title-page-in-numbering-via-preamble-settings-only with no help

my current settings are:

```
latex_elements = {
#...
'papersize': 'b5paper',
'babel' : '\\usepackage[english]{babel}',
'printindex': '\\footnotesize\\raggedright\\printindex',
'fncychap': r'\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}',
'preamble': '''%

''',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to change page numbers in LaTeX by setting the internal counter 'page' to the desired value.
This kind of commands should go in the 'preamble' section of your .conf file, which is presently empty and allows to issue global commands, add packages, etc.

```
latex_elements = {
#...
'papersize': 'b5paper',
'babel' : '\\usepackage[english]{babel}',
'printindex': '\\footnotesize\\raggedright\\printindex',
'fncychap': r'\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}',
'preamble': '''%
\setcounter{page}{150}
''',
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I have tried the setcounter command but it does not effect the page numbering. It is getting overwritten somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The `setcounter` solution has worked for me but I had to add it to the `maketitle` configuration option instead of `preamble`:

```
# conf.py
latex_elements = {
    ...
    'tableofcontents': ' ',
    'maketitle': r'''
        my title page...

        \clearpage
    
        \tableofcontents
        \setcounter{page}{2}

        \clearpage
```